# Node.js + Angular = Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I'm creating an Express.js API on a Node.js server. The API is used to access data stored on the server. I also keep a log of who's accessing the API in a database.

I'm trying to create an admin section that will use Angular.js to display the admin access logs neatly. I used the Angular Express Bootstrap seed to start my project:

https://github.com/jimakker/angular-express-bootstrap-seed/

My problem is that I need the controllers.js to access node modules but it doesn't seem to know that node exists. Here is my error:

```
controller.js

var mongo = require('mongodb');
[Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined]
```

How can I use node modules in Angular.js files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Node is a server side technology, you would not typically use your node modules on the browser with Angular.js. However, if you want commonjs require functionality in the browser see: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify.

Ofcourse, a browser can't talk to mongodb directly which is why you need an API in the first place, angular would communicate with your API using HTTP.

Angular.js makes an $http call to Node.js which requires and talks to the mongodb.

Comment: Thank you! I was starting to think I would need to use $http to hit a different route in my API to get data but I wasn't 100% and cant find an example of it anywhere. I swear I've been Googleing like a fiend before and after I posted here.