# browserify 'Error: Cannot find module' in trying to fix 'Uncaught reference error: require is not defined'

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, browserify

I am having a very similar, or almost exact, issue to @RachelD from this thread ([Node.js + Angular = Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195697/node-js-angular-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)) regarding the Uncaught reference error. However, when I run my 'browserify' command as stated in the directions here (https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) and exactly as shown below (I included my directory as well for reference)...

```
myname@compname:~/workspace/MyApp $ browserify /app/scripts/controllers/main.js > bundle.js
```

I am getting a 'Cannot find module' error

```
Error: Cannot find module '/app/scripts/controllers/main.js' from '/Users/myname/workspace/MyApp' 
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:35:25
at load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:53:43)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:59:22
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/browser-resolve/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:16:47
at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
```

How do I get past this error?

Answer (score 2):

You are using an absolute path: `/app/scripts/controllers/main.js`. You probably want `app/scripts/controllers/main.js`.