# browserify error 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function '

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, browserify

In reference to this question ([browserify 'Error: Cannot find module' in trying to fix 'Uncaught reference error: require is not defined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24985962/browserify-error-cannot-find-module-in-trying-to-fix-uncaught-reference-erro)), I got the browserify command to work thanks to stackoverflow community, however, I got another error that tells me

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function bundle.js:10786
Mime.load bundle.js:10786
(anonymous function) bundle.js:10822
_process bundle.js:10848
```

I believe the function it is complaining about is the 'fs.readFileSync' function. Here is the line 10786 in my 'bundle.js' file

```
Mime.prototype.load = function(file) {

  this._loading = file;
  // Read file and split into lines
  var map = {},
      content = fs.readFileSync(file, 'ascii'), <---LINE 10786
      lines = content.split(/[\r\n]+/);

  lines.forEach(function(line) {
    // Clean up whitespace/comments, and split into fields
    var fields = line.replace(/\s*#.*|^\s*|\s*$/g, '').split(/\s+/);
    map[fields.shift()] = fields;
  });

  this.define(map);

  this._loading = null;
};
```

Comment: Pro-tip: passing the `-d` or `--debug` flag to browserify will enable source maps, this makes it a lot easier to determine where errors occur in your code.

Comment: Hey Mike, should I call it like 'browserify app/index.js > app/bundle.js -d' or just 'browserify -d'

Comment: More like `browserify -d app/index.js > app/bundle.js`

Answer (score 3):

In general, you [cannot access the file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640177/browserify-with-requirefs) using Browserify since there's no file system for it to access (remember, you're running this on the web, not just your computer).

However, you can inline the contents of files using the [brfs module](https://github.com/substack/brfs).